# Why my search for faunaDB can't get any item?

Tags: faunadb

I'm stacking in searching faunaDB document by index. Please tell me what is wrong with my steps.

1. I have a document that has a value of externalID as "GBXzbXya".

[image]

2. I've created a index named **label_search_by_externalID** which has term as **externalID**

[image]

3. Then I've searched **GBXzbXya**, but I've got a blank array as follows:

[image]

Now, I've no idea what was wrong. Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the cause is the case mismatch. The document entry is **externalID** although Index term is **ExternalID**.